# Lag function to create new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a table with two columns and I want to create a new column based on adding both columns plus the result from the previous row. For example

```
 Xdate          X     Y
 2022-01-01     1     2
 2022-01-02     3     5
 2022-01-03     2     2
 2022-01-04     4     6
```

The result should look like this:

```
 Xdate         X      Y     Z
 2022-01-01    1      2     2 (1*2)
 2022-01-02    2      2     8 ((2+2)(from all previous row)) * 2)
 2022-01-03    2      1     12 ((2+8+2) (from all previous rows) * 1)
 2022-01-04    3      1     25 ((3+12+8+2) (from all previous rows) * 1)
```

So far I have this, but I can't figure out how to finish the query

```
  select
        *, 
        Lag(X+Y, 1, X+Y) OVER(ORDER BY Xdate) AS Z
  from temp
```

Comment: You're missing a column that defines the *previous row* - you can't order by Y as that will give a different non-determinant order (2,2,5,6) to that shown; you need a primary key such as an identity or date.

Comment: @Stu I've modified the table but I am still not getting the right result

Comment: As ***already*** mentioned *(in your duplicated questions)*, you ***can't*** use lag() to feed the result from one row in to the input for another row. Lag() can be applied to the inputs, not the outputs. You need a loop (bad in SQL) or recursion (fine for limited depths, but poor for arbitrarily large depths).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using a recursive CTE.  I added a ROW_NUMBER function just in case that there are gaps in your dates.

```
WITH cte_rn
AS
(
    SELECT xdate,x,y,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY xdate) as rn
    FROM #temp 
)
,
cte_rec
AS
( 
    SELECT cte_rn.xdate, cte_rn.x,cte_rn.y,cte_rn.rn,cte_rn.x * cte_rn.y as z , cte_rn.x * cte_rn.y as Zsum
    FROM cte_rn 
    WHERE rn = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.xdate,t.x,t.y,t.rn,(t.x + r.Zsum) * t.y as z ,r.Zsum+(t.x + r.Zsum) * t.y as Zsum
    FROM cte_rec r
    JOIN cte_rn t
        ON r.rn + 1 = t.rn
)
SELECT *
FROM cte_rec;
```